# FFmpeg streaming low CRF results in low quality

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, live-streaming, video-encoding

I am streaming(live chat) with FFmpeg using the following parameters.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -i video="device":audio="device" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency \
-c:a aac -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Unexpectedly, when CRF is lowered from 30 to 20, step-by-step. The stream quality decreases dramatically. When the CRF is about 20, sudden changes in the picture (like a head movement), seems to make the image green, gray or very distorted. I tried using CRF 30, and the problems seems to be gone. Why is this happening ?

I don't think it is a bandwidth issue given that I am on localhost. Also I didn't change anything based on I-frames.

**Edit:** I checked the file sizes given CRF 20 and CRF 30 on libx265.

*10 Second video.*

**CRF 20:** 1.7M

**CRF 30:** 350kb

Is 1.7M really bad for a 10 second stream that localhost or any other live streaming sevice can't handle ?

Comment: *I don't think it is a bandwidth issue given that I am on localhost.* --> confirm by saving to file and checking.

Comment: @Gyan Please check the edit.

Comment: You've reported file sizes but your original issue is with quality. How's the quality of 20 vs 30?

Comment: @Gyan Of course 20 is much better, however I don't need that much quality in a live chat program. Still I would use the best one possible. That's why I am delving into it.

Comment: @Gyan Take note that when saving to a file, both qualities are acceptable, it's when live decoding, 20 crf gives green, blurry, gray image. (during sudden movement, as I experienced)

Comment: So, not an encoding issue; either network transmission or the decoder at the receiver. Likely to be network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the resolution is, but it seems to be a performance issue for encoding. 
CRF=20 can also be used up to MAX 20 Mbps as a criterion of 720p. 
As a suggestion, do not use CRF but specify proper bitrates according to resolution.
720p -> 2.5Mbps
1080p -> 4Mbps

And 'dshow' is not very fast capture either. You have to take it into consideration.
I recommand DX10's swap-chain. It's super fast capturer.

Comment: Resolution is 640x480. And I added the filesizes on the edit. Also where can I find more information about DX10 swap-chain ? Is it available on DX11 and 12 (and better performance) ?

Comment: If you use that resolution, it's hard for you to get into trouble. I think you'd better look at the encoding options. And refer to this link.;; https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-getbuffer

Comment: and I recommand replace [CRF] to  [-b:v 840k]  (range: 750k~1000k)

Comment: and if you really want to use CRF, use this value [24] (range: 23~25)